# Window Menu "Selection" Event in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there an event that fires on a mdi child form when said form is selected in the "Window" menu of an mdi parent? I tried just detecting focus but I need to be able to know when the menu item is clicked even if the child window to which it corresponds is minimized.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Activated event. It fired when the form is on top

Comment: I tried that and actually it did not fire in all cases. This is especially an issue when the form being selected is ALREADY at the top of the z order.